# Capitialize first letter of words in a nested array

Tags: ruby, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to capitialize the starting letter of each word. This is my input:

```
[["aniket", 6], ["shivam", 7], ["tiwari", 8], ["abhijeet", 9]]
```

I need output:

```
[["Aniket", 6], ["Shivam", 7], ["Tiwari", 8], ["Abhijeet", 9]]
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: `.titleize` on string will do your job.

Comment: titleize does not work

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `titleize` is rails/activesupport

Comment: @aniket "capitalize first letter" is somehow ambiguous. *Capitalisation* means that the first letter in a word is uppercased and the remaining letters are lowercased (Ruby's [`capitalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) method works that way). Do you want to alter the whole word or just the first letter? Maybe it doesn't even matter because your initial words are always lowercase, but you should clarify that.

Comment: I need to capitalize first letter of each word.example stefan adams so output will be Stefan Adams .And I have already got an answer

Comment: @aniket you should [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), then. Note however that `capitalize` *does* affect the whole word (as described above), so the answer might not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this-

```
[["aniket", 6], ["shivam", 7], ["tiwari", 8], ["abhijeet", 9]].select {|arr| arr[0].capitalize!}
```

Comment: @aniket glad it worked for you! :)

Comment: Personal taste maybe but `select` only works here because `capitalize!` retuns a truthy value, `map` is more descriptive. It also doesn't require mutation of the original value, but returns a new one. If you want to mutate then maybe use `each`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate through the outer and inner array, constructing another one with the words capitalized:

```
output.map{|e| [e[0].capitalize, e[1]]}
```

`output` is your array.

Answer (score 4):

To change the array in-place I'd use [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
arr = [["aniket", 6], ["shivam", 7], ["tiwari", 8], ["abhijeet", 9]]

arr.each { |word, _| word.capitalize! }

arr #=> [["Aniket", 6], ["Shivam", 7], ["Tiwari", 8], ["Abhijeet", 9]]
```

`_` is a placeholder for an unused variable (because the 2nd element is not used in the block).

Note that [`capitalize!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) will change the whole string, i.e. `"fOO"` would become `"Foo"`. To just change the first character, you could use [`upcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-upcase):

```
arr.each { |word, _| word[0] = word[0].upcase }
```

To return a *new* array instead of altering the existing one, I'd use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
arr.map { |word, number| [word.sub(/./, &:upcase), number] }
```

`/./` is a regular expression that matches a single character. [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-sub) replaces the first match (i.e. the first character) with the return value of calling `upcase` (i.e. the uppercased letter).

Comment: What if the first element is "aB" or "Ab"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland "capitialize first letter" is ambiguous. The OP has to clarify what he / she wants.

Comment: You should perhaps state your assumption, presumably that all letters are lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

To addition, you can pass first and second array elements in block:

```
output.map {|f, s| [f.capitalize, s] }
```

Comment: `[["aB", 8]].map {|f, s| [f.capitalize, s] } #=> ["Ab", 8]`.